# Visual Studio - program ends before asynchronous tasks can finish - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous

There is probably an easy answer to this, I just can't find it and I'm new to C#.

Using Visual Studio, I've written a function that writes text to a file **asynchronously** (using async/await, and does not return anything), but it is called near the end of my program (that I'm testing it with), so now when it gets to `await`, the program continues from where I call the function from (which is near the end of my Main) while the text is busy writing to the file asynchronously.

My problem comes in, when the Main ends, the program finishes and quits all other asynchronous tasks, even before anything can be written to the file (because there is a whole process that it has to go through before it actually writes to the file). I can make my Main `sleep` for a second or two, but I'd much rather prefer to know how to wait for all background asynchronous tasks to finish before continuing (without using another await/async in the Main).

I know you probably thinking why don't I just make it synchronous since it's at the end of the program (which I am testing it with), but I need it this way, and would like to know how to do this.

```
void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("This is an error\n");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError.ToFile(ex);
    }
    //need code here to wait for background processes to finish before ending
}

public class LogError
{
    static public void ToFile(Exception excep)
    {
        Task.Run(() => LogErrorToFile(excep));
    }

    static public async Task LogErrorToFile(Exception excep)
    {
        //writes to file using await
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from C# 6.0 you can use `await` in `catch` block and from C# 7.0/7.1 you can use `async Main` so you code could be rewritten to this

```
async void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("This is an error\n");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await LogError.LogErrorToFile(ex);
    }
}
```

If you can't use that you need to either expose this `Task` that is used and wait for it to finish or use some kind of synchronization mechanism like `ManualResetEvent`.

Comment: Thanks, this did work. I had to add `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` to my `.csproj` file first.
I also has to change the return type of the Main to `Task` instead of `void` (and also add the `static` keyword)

Comment: You can set that from VS 2017. In Build->Advanced

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not wait until the task is completed. Use `Task.Wait` for waiting task completion. Or `Task.WaitAll` for waiting completion of multiple tasks. For it you must collect all tasks in buffer, for example, `List<Task>`

```cs
void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("This is an error\n");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError.ToFile(ex);
    }
    LogError.WaitForCompletion();
    //need code here to wait for background processes to finish before ending
}

public class LogError
{
    private static Task _tasks = new List<Task>();

    static public void ToFile(Exception excep)
    {
        _tasks.add(Task.Run(() => LogErrorToFile(excep)));
    }

    static public async Task LogErrorToFile(Exception excep)
    {
        //writes to file using await
    }

    public static void WaitForCompletion() {
        Task.WaitAll(_tasks);
    }
}
```

This code is not for production, because in it field `_tasks` can accumulate a lot of already completed tasks. Use it only as an example for thinking.